# Dealing with password vault recovery after a catastrophic failure as a home user

Tags: password-management, data-recovery

I had a dinner with some friends today, and I mentioned that I use 1Password combined with Dropbox to manage my password. One of them then remarked something which I actually hadn't considered: because both my Dropbox password and the password for the email address I use for recovery are also in the vault and completely random, I have no way of recovering from a catastrophic failure where all the local copies of my vault become unusable.

Now, I do have the possibility of resetting my recovery email password, but that requires me to be connected from my home network, and I might not have that luxury. The obvious answer is an offsite backup, but I'm unsure where to place that. My instinct is to share the vault folder with someone I can trust via dropbox, but that could increase the chance of a compromise, and without the enhanced permissions from Premium Dropbox, there's a chance of vault corruption on my end. There are solutions like a notary or a bank safe, but those are not cheap, plus it's still something that might be compromised.

I am unsure of how to solve this issue affordably. It might never happen, but all it takes is a fire in my bedroom while I'm downstairs that destroys my phone, my laptop and my desktop to put me in deep trouble. How can I recover my password vault if all my local copies have been lost and the only copy left is on my dropbox, which i can't access without my password vault?

Comment: Print your dropbox and email passwords and stick them in your wallet. If that's not good enough, put them in a sealed envelope in your parent's desk  drawer or something.

Answer (score 1):

I would memorize the master passwords.  You could have a physical backup in case you forget them. I would recommend reading [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/22587/how-to-easily-remember-lots-of-different-passwords) topic for a full discussion.

Answer (score 0):

I use both **Bitwarden** and **KeePassXC** for **redundant** password managers. It only takes a few more seconds to enter new entries and changes into both databases. It is free insurance if either service is not functioning.

I keep a local **backup copy** of my pw vault on a Samsung FIT+ **flash drive** in a fireproof waterproof digital media **safe**. I also keep several important passwords in the safe, **written** on paper and inscribed on an **aluminum sheet** for high fire temperature protection.

You can also keep another backup copy on a flash drive or a tiny **SDXC memory card** in an off-site secret location, at work, buried in a sealed container, or in your vehicle.  You can buy a small **vehicle safe** for your trunk.

I keep a remote backup copy on encrypted **Proton Drive** in Switzerland. I do not use any Big Tech snoop storage.

I do not keep passwords in my wallet.

I bought a used fireproof waterproof portable [**Sentry chest safe**](https://abclegaldocs.com/blog-Colorado-Notary/sentrysafe-chw20221-fireproof-waterproof-chest/) on **eBay** for a low price.  It had a few scratches that did not affect its security.